# Clipping/Masking On A Timeline/Tweened Frames On Photoshop CS5 and Up

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mask, gif, clipping-mask

Good day, Art Creators!

I have a questions with regards of clipping or masking a certain part of a GIF that I'm making - I'm not sure how would I explain it, but I'd rather show it below:

Here's what I currently have,

[image]

What I want is to clip or mask the excess 'icons' in a way that it only show on the red part and not on the transparent background.

I've tried deleting the excess on the layer whilst all the tweened frames are selected, but that 're=shapes' the 'icons' and plays them through the red part.

To provide a better example of what I want to achieve, here's a still image:

[image: Any ideas?]

Comment: Confusing... *"in a way that it only show on the red part"* then.... *"but that ... plays them through the red part"* So, which is it?

Comment: The screenshots and information you provide only give explanation for a static image; for animation it requires a different line of thought. How are the icons built? i.e. Are they on their own layer? Are they animated? How do they relate to each frame of your animation? Every frame of the animation can be seen as a single image, with different settings in the layers palette. Therefore we would need to know what those settings are in order to figure out how to apply them to each frame.